# dashboard.example.com/link1/* to be served as link1.example.com/* always

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, apache2, proxypass

I tried to find all over and didn't find any proper answer. I'm pretty sure this must be a duplicate but please direct me to the right answer.

So this is my case.
The project is at dashboard.example.com/link1 and there are 'n' number of other links like dashboard.example.com/link1/sub1, dashboard.example.com/link1/sub1/sub2 and so on...
But, I want it to be served in the URL as link1.example.com/sub1, link1.example.com/sub1/sub2 and so on...

I tried something like this in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashboard\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(/.*)?$ http://$1.example.com$2 [L,R=301]
```

By doing this I was successfully able to redirect to `link1.example.com`
But yes, that doesn't have the project content that I wanted (`dashboard.example.com/link1`)

I also previously tried to use proxy as follows and wasn't successful.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName link1.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost/dashboard/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/dashboard/
</VirtualHost>
```

I know I'm not just there, Thank you for making an attempt to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best course of action is to add link1.example.com as ServerAlias to the dashboard.example.com VHost and rewrite the URLs properly when the Host header is link1.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashboard\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(/.*)?$ http://$1.example.com$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^link1\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /link1/$1 [L]
```

Something like this. I haven't tested it but it *should* work.

Comment: Hey, this do work for me :) But just to add up on this - how to do pattern match to the condition with link1? Coz, currently it even dashboard.example.com/login is been directed to login.example.com, which is not needed.

Comment: Edit the first rewrite rule as ^link1/(....)...

Comment: The second rewrite rule is causing a problem - I am seeing link1.example.com/link1. And 500 server error. When I comment the rule I don't get error, but shows the homepage instead.

Comment: You can learn how to check the logs and see what causes the 500. This is not a help channel. Most likely it's a redirect loop and you can easily see it if you enable rewrite debug log. The solution will be to add one more condition that only does the rewrite if the path doesn't already begin with /link1/.